# Sentence meaning - a waste of

Tags: meaning

I came across this in a novel “The fingers of my successor daily turned the handle of this door which opened now on the yellow flame of the gas-fire, pink-shaded lamps burning through the snow-grey afternoon, a waste of cretonne loose covers.”

Could anyone help clarify why “a waste of cretonne loose covers”? Covers mean curtains? The room is so well illuminated that it doesn’t need curtains?

Answer (score 1):

*Loose covers* are fitted covers for upholstered armchairs, to protect the upholstery or hide it when it is worn out. I think the author is using *waste* in the sense of *area of barren land* (see https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/waste , noun definition 3). A *snowy waste* is a large area of empty land covered in snow, and the room is seen as an unprofitable area covered in cretonne (furnishing fabric).

Comment: In the US, such coverings are called slipcovers. Loose covers in the UK?

Comment: @KarlG Yes, that is what we call them.